# How can I tell h2o deep learning grid to have AUC instead of residual deviance

Tags: r, h2o, auc

I would like to measure models performance by looking for AUC or Accuracy. In the grid search I get results with `residual deviance`,how can I tell h2o deep learning grid to have AUC instead of residual deviance and present the results as atable like the one attached below ?

```
train <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     snakes
                              0        9         7 a
                              0        8         4 b
                              1        2         8 c
                              1        2         3 a
                              1        8         3 a
                              0        1         2 a
                              0        7         1 b
                              0        1         5 c
                              1        9         7 c
                              1        8         7 c
                              0        2         7 b
                              1        2         3 b
                              1        6         3 c
                              0        1         1 a
                              0        3         9 a
                              1        1         1 b ",header = TRUE)
trainHex <- as.h2o(train)

g <- h2o.grid("deeplearning",
              hyper_params = list(
                  seed = c(123456789,12345678,1234567),
                  activation = c("Rectifier", "Tanh", "TanhWithDropout", "RectifierWithDropout", "Maxout", "MaxoutWithDropout")
              ),
              reproducible = TRUE,
              x = 2:4,
              y = 1,
              training_frame = trainHex,
              validation_frame = trainHex,
              epochs = 50,
              )
g
model_ids <- g@summary_table
model_ids<-as.data.frame(model_ids)
```

The results table that I got:

```
     Hyper-Parameter Search Summary: ordered by increasing residual_deviance
             activation      seed                                                  model_ids   residual_deviance
1                Maxout  12345678 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_10 0.07243775676256235
2                Maxout   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_16 0.10060885040861599
3     MaxoutWithDropout 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_5  0.1706496158406441
4                Maxout 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_4 0.17243125875659948
5                  Tanh 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_1 0.18326527198894926
6                  Tanh  12345678  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_7 0.18763395264761593
7                  Tanh   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_13 0.18791531211136187
8       TanhWithDropout 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_2 0.19808063817007837
9       TanhWithDropout  12345678  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_8 0.19815190962052193
10      TanhWithDropout   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_14 0.19832946889767458
11            Rectifier 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_0 0.20679125165086842
12    MaxoutWithDropout   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_17 0.21971759565380736
13 RectifierWithDropout 123456789  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_3 0.22337599298253263
14    MaxoutWithDropout  12345678 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_11 0.22440661112729862
15 RectifierWithDropout   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_15  0.2284671685474275
16 RectifierWithDropout  12345678  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_9 0.23163744415703522
17            Rectifier   1234567 Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_12  0.2516917276707789
18            Rectifier  12345678  Grid_DeepLearning_train_model_R_1483217086840_112_model_6  0.2642221616447725
```

Comment: BTW, setting `validation_frame` to be the same as `training_frame` is the default behaviour, so no need to specify it. Be aware that by not using validation and test data sets you are optimizing for deep learning parameters that *over-fit* best.  I'm not even sure what you learn about the effect of random seed on the variation of results can apply to unseen data.  (Of course it can still be an interesting experiment: e.g. I've done this before to see how few hidden nodes/layers/epochs are needed to fit the data perfectly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `h2o.getGrid()`. Following on from your example code:

```
g_rmse <- h2o.getGrid(g@grid_id, "rmse")
g_rmse  #Output it
```

I've chosen root-MSE there. AUC is not available for your sample data: it has to be a binomial classification, and you are doing a regression.

The reason you are doing a regression is your `y` contains 0 and 1, so H2O has guessed it is numeric. You need to use `as.factor()` on that column, just after uploading it into H2O.

```
train <-  ...
trainHex <- as.h2o(train)
trainHex[,1] = as.factor(trainHex[,1])  #Add this

g <- ...
```

Then you can do this:

```
g_auc <- h2o.getGrid(g@grid_id, "auc", decreasing = TRUE)
g_auc
```

I've set it to `decreasing=TRUE` so that the best AUC is at the top.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you detailed answer @Darren Cook.