# h2o Flow UI: Build Model but no ROC CURVE or AUC for multiclass?

Tags: machine-learning, enums, random-forest, h2o, roc

Reference to https://dzone.com/articles/machine-learning-with-h2o-hands-on-guide-for-data

I was able to follow the example and plotted the ROC and AUC curve but when I did the same thing with my data, I have "SCORING HISTORY - DEVIANCE" instead of "SCORING HISTORY - LOGLOSS" and my "ROC CURVE - TRAINING METRICS" did not appear.

My dataset has 2 classes, 0, 1 instead of yes and no from the example. What determines whether the ROC curve will be portable?

Updated 10 Jul 2019 reference to Maurever's reply: 
I have "convert to enum" for my response "label" and change distribution to "bernoulli" but I still can't plot ROC. 
[image]

Update: For future users who has the same encounter as me. Seems like h2o cannot use response with class as "0" and "1" even if you convert to enum. My problem is solved by relabel of 0 and 1 to "Normal" and "Malicious" and the ROC curve will be plot.

Comment: I only just saw your update. As long as you convert the data H2O can use response code of "0" and "1".  The problem is that you have `ENUM(3)` not `ENUM(2)`. In other words, you have some other value in your data. It might be a "2", but more likely it is a space or something. Possibly just one row. Clean the data and try again. Sorting in a spreadsheet by that column should find it easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the type of response column to "enum",

[image]

or change distribution in the model parameters setting to "bernoulli" (binomial classification).

[image]

In the image, you share there is "Enum(3)" so the result is multinomial classification not binomial. So you should see Confusion Matrix but not the ROC curve. The ROC curve is able to display only for 2-class classification (more about ROC here: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5).

You should see something like this (if you set distribution to "multinomial"):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> My dataset has 2 classes, 0, 1 instead of yes and no from the example.

What will have happened is that H2O has decided that was a numeric column, rather than a categorical (aka factor) column. The fix is simply to use `as.factor()` on that column. Do this just after importing the data, but before using it to build a model.

Then it will know to build a classification model, not a regression model, and you will get the metrics you expect to see.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441578/841830 (or search for as.factor in the H2O docs, where you will find loads more)

**In Flow**, you first upload the file, then you click parse files, and it shows a list of the columns. The categorical/factor columns are called "Enum" there (yes, it is confusing). Your column is presumably showing as numeric, so go to the dropdown box and change it to be enum. Then start the parse. Then, after that, build your model.

Comment: Hi, may I know how to set as factor in h2o Flow UI?

Comment: Following the example, the factor was type enum so I have set my response as enum when I parsed the data in Flow but still, no ROC curve plotted.

Comment: I have manually set my respond column as factor in command line, write back as csv in local and follow the example again, and I still can't get h2o to plot ROC curve. Please help.

Comment: @user1342124 The reference in your question was R code, so I assumed you were using R! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey Darren I did `df['target_cured'] = df['target_cured'].astype('category')` prior to `hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)` and still got `H2OValueError: auc() is only available for Binomial classifiers.`

Comment: @the775 Check in Flow to see what data type actually got imported. That is Python code? Should be `df['target_cured'].asfactor()` See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/change-column-type.html#changing-the-column-type

Comment: Hi Darren, I found the error. I was trying to cast my `df['target_cured']` to a category **before** casting to an H2OFrame. Needed to cast to H2OFrame, `hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)` then run `hf['target_cured'] = hf['target_cured'].asfactor()`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed by changing the target variable from 0s and 1s to False and True values.